# use mmap to read from /dev/mem

Tags: c, mmap

I'm try to read from the physical address.

the output of the printf function is empty:"value="

What I did wrong?

```
int counter;
int fd;
char* mmap_res;

fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);

if (fd == -1)
{
    printf("can not access /dev/mem\n" );
    return -1;
}

mmap_res =
    (char*)mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x92000000);

for (counter = 0; counter < 10 ; counter++)
    printf("value=%c\n",mmap_res[counter]);

if (mmap_res == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("mmap failed\n" );
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your process has the necessary permissions? By default you can’t just read and write `/dev/mem` willy-nilly. And where did you get the offset from?

Comment: You should check for `mmap` failure _before_ for `for` loop because `mmap_res[counter]` may be invalid. Also, perhaps the characters are unprintable? Try printing the character codes instead, e.g. `printf("value=%d\n", mmap_res[counter]);`.

Comment: What's the OS version and architecture? What is at physical address 0x92000000 - RAM, PCI region, …?